# Send location updates when device is locked

Tags: android, location, android-service

In my app on a particular screen, I send location updates to the server even after the screen is locked.

Below is the `GPSTracker` service class that's used to track the location updates.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    public static CommonInterfaces.UpdateLocationDelegate delegate;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    private static final  int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION = 0;

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    public static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 20 meters

    public static final long MAX_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 45; // considering 100 miles/hr

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000; // location update is based on distance, thus the value here is 0 ;//1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(){
        mContext = null;
    }

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)mContext, new String[]{
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 10);
        }

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // No network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled)  {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
//                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isNetworkEnabled && (location == null)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }


    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog.
     * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing the Settings button.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // On pressing the cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.onUpdateLocation(location);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `onLocationChanged` method detects a location change and calls the delegate method. But this service is not updating the location when the device is locked for more than 5min. I'm guessing android is going to sleep mode, and killing the app in the background. Is there anyway that I could send the location updates when device is locked and avoid going to sleep mode?

Comment: Not your current problem but-  don't use this code.  This class is totally broken, and will not work most of the time.  See my writeup on it and alternative at http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I´ve worked a lot in this field (in getting frequent location updates "forever"). If you need several location updates per hour, the only way to do this is to make your service to be in Foreground (with START_STICKY - see sample for this). The service can live almost "forever" if it keeps in the foreground (even in [Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html?hl=es-419)). In Doze Mode is possible that the location updates stops because some sensors "sleep" but the service must not be affected in Doze Mode.

You can refer to the next google sample: [Location Updates in Foreground Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService)

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that a foreground service can also be killed by Android if it needs too (low memory, etc), but a foreground will be one last things to be shutdown by Android.

Comment: for the foreground service, isn't the device supposed to be awake all the time?

Comment: The foreground service will be executing even in Doze Mode (device deep sleep). Check my edited answer to check a Google Sample.